# How: sfForkedDoctrineApply Custom Registration Form

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am very new to Symfony 1.4 and basically know just how to create basic actions/templates.  I have install the sfDoctrineGuard and the sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin which provides for user registration, e-mail validation, etc.  That is all working just as expected, but I really want to add extra fields to the user registration form.

I've followed the instructions to add the necessary fields into the schema, but I am stumped at actually showing those required fields on the registration page with sfApply.  I tried and tried to follow the instructions provided by sfDoctrineApply and sfForkedDoctrineApply, but they are just a tad too vague for my level of Symonfy knowledge.

Comment: Can you post your sfApplyApplyForm and your schema?What exactly you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the forms under /plugins/sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin/lib/form .
check out http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/01-Form-Creation for the forms itself.